# SBT 1.3.x : How to set a custom artifactPattern

Tags: sbt

I have the follow task to publish a custom artifact (in this case a gz file) in ivy format to a remote artifactory.

```
 val publishImageTask = publishImageKey := {
  println("Publishing gz file ...")
  val extracted = Project.extract(state.value)
  Project.runTask(publish, extracted.append(List(
    publishTo := Some("MyArtifactory" at "https://xxx/artifactory/"),
    publishMavenStyle := false,
    isSnapshot := true,
    publishArtifact in Compile := false,
    publishArtifact in Test := false,
    organization := "com.example.my",
    moduleName := "myproject",
    crossPaths := false,
    credentials += Credentials(credentialsFile),
    description := "A gz file",
    version := "1.0.0",

    packagedArtifacts in publish := {
      val gzFile =  new File("/tmp/foo.tar.gz")
      println(s"gzFile:$gzFile")
      val artifact = Artifact(name="foo",  `type` = "release", extension = "tar.gz")
      Map(artifact -> gzFile)

    }
  ), state.value), true)
}
```

The above task will try to publish to

```
https://xxx/artifactory/com/example/my/myproject/1.0.0/foo-1.0.0.tar.gz
```

It seems the above is using artifactPattern

```
[organisation]/[module](_[scalaVersion])(_[sbtVersion])/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

In sbt, how to set a custom artifactPattern

```
[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier])-[revision].[ext]
```

so that the URL includes the type "release"

```
https://xxx/artifactory/com/example/my/myproject/1.0.0/releases/foo.tar-1.0.0.gz

Thanks in advance for any assistance ! 
Shing
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the artifactPattern could be specified in  URLRepository, which extends Resolver.  In instead of

```
publishTo := Some("MyArtifactory" at "https://xxx/artifactory/"),
```

use

```
  val repoUrl = "https://xxx/artifactory/"
  
  val resolver = URLRepository(
    name = "DockerImageRepo",
    patterns = Patterns(
      ivyPatterns =Vector(s"${repoUrl}/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/ivy-[revision].xml"),    
      artifactPatterns = Vector(s"${repoUrl}/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier])-[revision].[ext]"),
      isMavenCompatible = true,
      descriptorOptional = false,
      skipConsistencyCheck = true
    )
  )

 publishTo := Option(resolver)
```